# Update only a portion of an entity

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I have a view model which has an observableArray of entities retrieved via Breeze.

```
// define the viewmodel
function episodesViewModel() {

this.episodes = ko.observableArray();
...
}
```

Each episode entity has a series of properties which I want populating in their entirety on page load. How can I then update only one of those properties on retrieval from and when saving back to the server? The other properties are much larger and will remain static so there's no point sending them back and forth over the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Great question!**

My first question to you is "*are you sure that the payload weight of the extra 'static properties' is actually a problem*?"  I have to ask you ... as I would have to ask myself ... because I have a predilection for anticipating problems and solving them prematurely. After measuring I discover that all that work and worry really didn't matter for the application-in-the-field. Please forgive my impertinence.

Let us assume that you really do have a problem. The `episode` object is extremely heavy (perhaps with image data) and you can't split it in your model into `Episode` and `EpisodeDetail` classes with a 1-to-1 relationship between them. You are stuck with one big, fat `Epsiode` class. I know this happens. Just checking.

You can do what you desire. I want to make this scenario easier in Breeze. There is an "OK" way to do it today (some might call it a hack). I'll layout the outline of it for you here. You can try it ... and let us know how to refine it.

1. Create a DTO class (`EpisodeSaveDto`?) on the server that represents the shape of the `Episode` object you want to save. It must have the `Id` and the properties you'd want to save.
2. It won't be part of the normal metadata coming from the server because it's not a real entity. So describe that DTO object in metadata in JavaScript on your BreezeJS client. Breeze will then treat your `EpisodeSaveDto` as an entity. See the ["NoDb" Sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/nodb) for an example of this technique.
3. Create instances of `EpisodeSaveDto` and populate them with your changes. You're updating, not adding new instances, so use the [EntityState-setting signature on the `createEntity`](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_createEntity) method.

   ```
   var episode = manager.createEntity("EpisodeDto", 
      { id: origEpisode.id, 
        foo: changedFooValue }, 
      EntityState.Modified);
   ```
4. On the server, in your custom (derived) `EFContextProvider`, override the `BeforeSaveEntities` method. This method receives a dictionary of changed entities, arranged by type.
5. Remove the collection of `EpisodeSaveDto` changes and process them into appropriate `Episode` entities for save. If you're not using EF or a SQL Db, than you'll be doing this in your implementation of `ContextProvider` ... again as shown in the ["NoDb" Sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/nodb).
6. Add a collection of your ready-to-save `Episode` entities to the dictionary of changed entities and attach them also to the EF context.

Breeze.NET on the server will save your manufactured `Episode` entity on the server and ignore the incoming `EpisodeSaveDto` (which it wouldn't know how to save anyway).

*Confession: I'm writing this from memory and I'm a little fuzzy on step #6. I trust you get the idea. We're kind of faking Breeze.NET out.*

As I said at the beginning, I'd like to make this scenario much easier. I'd like to see a built in support for "Commands" that can accept and return entity sets.  Please add your vote to [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions) if this is something you think we should do.

Comment: Is this how you would handle cases where only the server should be allowed to update some fields of an entity such as CreatedBy and UpdatedBy fields, or would you handle CreatedBy and UpdatedBy some other way by refactoring the model or doing something else?

Comment: I'm looking into implementing a solution similar to what you have explained above. My main reason for not using the entity class directly in breeze is due to validation. It's used in two different views and the validation is slightly different. So, say I don't have data annotations in my Entity class but they are in my DTO. Will my DTO be validated in the server side? if so does it happen before the call to `BeforeSaveEntity`?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can go the traditional route with an out-of-band AJAX call.

Add your own Web API controller action method that responds to HTTP PATCH. You make it do the right thing.

Call it from the client (using jQuery AJAX or amplify.js) with the changed `Episode` data. This is straight-up WebAPI/AJAX programming.

If the user made the changes directly to `Episode` entities, you'll have to adjust them according to what happens with your out-of-band save. `EntityManager.getChanges('Episode')` will give you changed `Episode` entities from cache. After the save completes successfully, in the callback you can call `episode.entityAspect.acceptChanges` to tell the Breeze `EntityManager` that the `episode` is no longer in a changed state.

Comment: What would you expect the out of band API controller method to look like and return, if you were doing something like "public ?? CustomSaveEpisodeDto(EpisodeDto episodeDto) { ... }"?